# What type will make "std::has_unique_object_representations" return false?

Tags: c++, standards, c++17, type-traits

At [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/has_unique_object_representations), I see a weird **type trait checker**: `std::has_unique_object_representations`

From its description, I cannot imagine any type `T` that make `std::has_unique_object_representations<T>::value` is `false`.

Is there any counter-example?

Comment: The wording here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/has_unique_object_representations implies T needs to be trivially copyable and also gives some reasoning.

Comment: IEEE 754-compatible floats are a counterexample, because the representations of positive and negative zeros differ, but their values are obviously equal.

Comment: Also, any type with more than zero total padding bits.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Understanding the purpose of this trait requires understanding the distinction between an objects "value representation" and its "object representation". From the standard:

> The *object representation* of an object of type `T` is the sequence of N unsigned char objects taken up by the object of type `T`, where N equals `sizeof(T)`. The *value representation* of an object is the set of bits that hold the value of type `T` . For trivially copyable types, the value representation is a set of bits in the object representation that determines a value, which is one discrete element of an implementation-defined set of values.

So, object representation is the total storage of an object. But consider the following object:

```
struct T
{
  char c;
  int i;
};
```

On many systems, `sizeof(T)` will be 8. Why? Because `int` has to be 4-byte aligned, so the compiler inserts 3 bytes of padding between `c` and `i`. Since those three bytes are part of the object's storage (based on `sizeof(T)`), they are part of the object's object representation.

But those three bytes are *not* part of its value representation. If you modified those bytes, they would not affect the values of `c` or `i`, or anything else about them.

If you wrote an `operator==` overload for `T`, changes to those bytes would not affect its results. Which also means that if you did write an `operator==` overload, it *could not* be implemented like this:

```
bool operator==(const T &lhs, const T &rhs)
{
  return std::memcmp(&lhs, &rhs, sizeof(T)) == 0;
}
```

Why not? Because two `T`s can have different values for those padding bytes, but still have the same value of `c` and `i`. And thus they have the same value representation and thus should be considered equivalent.

`has_unique_object_representations` is true when `T`'s object representation and its value representation exactly overlay one another (and when `T` is trivially copyable). So, when would you care about this?

You can write a generalized hashing function that works on any trivially copyable type `T` by reading its value representation as an array of bytes and hashing them. Well, you *could* do that, but only if the type doesn't have padding bytes. And that's what `has_unique_object_representations` tells you: that all of the bytes in the object representation matter.

Also, note that `float` types, won't necessarily have this value be true, since binary equality and floating-point equality aren't the same thing in IEEE-754. So types which contain `float`s will also not necessarily have this be true. Indeed, implementations that use one's-complement signed integers, or signed integers with trap representations, will also not have this be true for such types.

Comment: I think you're missing a `sizeof(T)` in the `memcmp` call.

Comment: What about types that have float like behavior but are  user types? I mean in theory I could have struct that has one uint32 member but implement all operations on it as if it was float member. In other words it would be a struct Float{ uint32 f};  with all operations implmemented so that Float behaves as built in float. Also I imagine string classes would not fit this...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Well, that's a good point, but in many cases, the TriviallyCopyable restriction will cull those out (like the string case). After all, even though your `Float::operator==` won't care about certain bits, as far as the language is concerned, they're still there and they still matter.

Comment: Why is the name of the trait in plural form? Even the [`documentation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/has_unique_object_representations) describes it as *"...if any two objects of type T with the same value have the same object **representation**"*.